# How to display data from view model correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

In my viewModel i get result.data:

> accounts: [Account(accountId=461715f3-038c-4c3d-ac3c-1fac44f37f14, currency=GBP, description=Personal, nickname=Sydney Beard)]

Here is the code of ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class AccountListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getAccountsUseCase: GetAccountsUseCase,
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {

    private val _state = mutableStateOf<AccountListState>(AccountListState())
    val state: State<AccountListState> = _state

    init {
        savedStateHandle.get<String>(Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN)?.let { accessToken ->
            getAccounts(accessToken = accessToken)
        }
    }

    private fun getAccounts(accessToken: String) {
        getAccountsUseCase(accessToken = accessToken).onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _state.value = AccountListState(accounts = result.data ?: emptyList())
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    _state.value = AccountListState(error = result.message ?: "Something went wrong")
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _state.value = AccountListState(isLoading = true)
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }
}
```

In my screen in log i see that i get account:

> account: Account(accountId=461715f3-038c-4c3d-ac3c-1fac44f37f14, currency=GBP, description=Personal, nickname=Sydney Beard)

Here is code of my screen:

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun OverviewScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: AccountListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val state = viewModel.state.value
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            items(state.accounts) { account ->
                Log.d("some", "account: $account")
                AccountListItem(
                    account = account,
                    onItemClick = {
                        navController.navigate(Screen.AccountDetail.route + "/${account.accountId}")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        if (state.error.isNotBlank()) {
            Text(
                text = state.error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 20.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            )
        }
        if (state.isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I can't see anything on the screen, although this is how I display my account.

Q: how to display my account, because now many times I have the `getAccounts` method called which is why the screen is redrawn every time

**UPDATE**

I check my `AccountListViewModel` instance and in method `getAccounts()` put the next log:

```
Log.d("some", "getAccounts: ${result.data} vm: ${this.toString()}")
```

And see that and I saw that every time the view model is recreated:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Compose you have to collect your flow as a state. You are only reading flow once in your code.

You are also using state in ViewModel which is bad. Use flow there.

Fixes in ViewModel:

```kotlin
// wrong
private val _state = mutableStateOf<AccountListState>(AccountListState())
    val state: State<AccountListState> = _state

// correct
private val _state = MutableStateFlow<AccountListState>(AccountListState())
    val state: StateFlow<AccountListState> = _state
```

And fixed in compose:

```kotlin
// wrong
val state = viewModel.state.value

// correct
val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()
```

Read more here: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow).collectAsState(kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext)

Comment: I can't in my screen write smth like this: `val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()` because `collectAsState` unresolved reference.

Comment: Then import it. Those are in base compose libraries. `import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState` and probably `import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue`

Comment: Added imports, but they unused. Also get next message:
`public fun <T> StateFlow<TypeVariable(T)>.collectAsState(context: CoroutineContext = ...): State<TypeVariable(T)> defined in androidx.compose.runtime`

Comment: That's not an error, it's just a message

Comment: I wrote that this is a message but a message for an unresolved reference: `collectAsState`.

Comment: But this message points directly to proper reference, so i really do not understand the issue you have. In Android Studio i have automatic import options right after i write `collectAsState` and hit alt + enter

Comment: @Morozov you were using `State` instead of `StateFlow` in ViewModel. Updated the answer

Comment: Check please UPDATE, i think that i found the main problem

Comment: The only i have is that you are recomposing `OverviewScreen` over and over again for some reason? It seems like a real problem is outside the code you shared and more in the navigation layer

Comment: Yes, you were right, the reason for re-creating the view model was incorrect navigation, which was no covered in the question. sorry.  In any case, your answer prompted the right thoughts